# Fiware Keyrock how to authenticate from python-keystoneclient

Tags: fiware, keystone

I am using fiware-idm. I find python-keystone client to to interact with keystone API with easy way . 
But I have problem with authentication.  creating regular user with default "idm" user it's not problem . but i can not find way how to autenticate this user.

here is my test samples : 
create user :

```
def create_user():
   user = keystone.users.create(name="user4",
                             default_project="idm",
                             domain="default",
                             password="qwerty",
                             email="user4@email.com",
                             description="this is user description",
                             enabled=True,
                             username="user4")
   return user
```

authentication:

```
auth = v3.Password(auth_url="http://192.168.33.10:5001/v3",
               username="user4",
               password="qwerty",
               domain_name="idm"
               )
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
keystone = client.Client(session=sess)
print keystone.users.list()
```

It writes that :

```
keystoneclient.exceptions.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)
```

Comment: you are creating the user in "default" domain and authenticating it in "idm" domain

Comment: @ÁlvaroAlonso  can you tell me why I don't have client id and client secret key in my application .  This is in Keyrock instance hosted by FIWARE Cloud Portal  http://screencloud.net/v/pqc6

Comment: It seems you are not the owner of that application

Comment: I think i am owner of this aplication I create application with user which i am logged in now , when i am creating application with current user this credentials is still not available . http://i.imgur.com/TN1Vq5e.png

Comment: please, check you have the role "provider" in the application

Comment: Alvaro I have no problem if i am creating application from public portal https://account.lab.fiware.org . I have problem at Keyrock image from FIWARE cloud protal . 
We are going to make registration as service  and once you wrote us that it's not available to make things like this from public instance . And we should go to install own instance or use Keyrock image from Fiware Portal. This image is new in cloud portal , it's was added month ago .

Answer (score 0):

Answering you last comment, @beka, it seems to be an issue on the Cloud Portal images for version 4.4.1.

It will be fixed in versión 5.1.0, which will be released this week, so I recommend you to use that version images.

Comment: it is now available.